# How to tokenize compound words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, tokenize

Having an original list element such as `["southnorth"]`, I'd like to add a space based on the list `["south", "north", "island"]`. Then, the list would be changed from `['southnorth']` to `['south','north']` as long as the list which we base the tokenization contains `['south', 'north']`.

However, if there is a list `["south", "island"]` then the list `["southnorth"]` should be kept together as it is.

I thought in something as follow:

```
list1= ['southnorth']
#list2= ['south','north','island']
list2=['south','island']

str1= " ".join(list1)
str2= " ".join(list2)

Get the alternators to apply regex:
list_compound = sorted(list1 + list2, key=len)
alternators = '|'.join(map(re.escape, list_compound)
regex = re.compile(r''.format(alternators)

str1_split = re.sub(r'({})'.format(alternators),r'\1 ',str1,0, re.IGNORECASE)

str2_split = re.sub(r'({})'.format(alternators),r'\1 ',str2,0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

However, the above is failing because I need to ensure the order of the sequences. For instance, to decompose `["southnorth"]` I need to ensure the other list has `["south", "north"]`. Otherwise, keep it in the original form.

Comment: Can you have more than two parts in the combined string?

Comment: What if your string is `southwestnorth`? Do you expect the output to be `southwest north` or `south westnorth`?

Comment: I would keep the original form of  `southwestnorth` because the only way to tokenize is that `south` and `north` were contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution and probably not the best performing, but here is a trivial brute force attempt:

```
def tokenize(word, tokens):
    tokenized_word = word
    for t in tokens:
        tokenized_word = tokenized_word.replace(t, f"{t} ").strip()

    for w in tokenized_word.split(" "):
        if w.strip() not in tokens:
            return word

    return tokenized_word


tokens = ["south", "north", "island"]

assert tokenize("south", tokens) == "south"
assert tokenize("southnorth", tokens) == "south north"
assert tokenize("islandsouthnorth", tokens) == "island south north"
assert tokenize("southwestnorth", tokens) == "southwestnorth"
```